# How can I get images and description from Amazon's Product Advertising API?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I am using the [Amazon Product Advertising API (formerly ECS)](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) in PHP to get product information using an ASIN code. I can get the information but images and product descriptions are missing. I've looked around the API class and couldn't find anything helpful. The code I am using to get the product details is:

```
$client = new AmazonECS(get_option('awskey'), get_option('awssecret'), 'UK'); 
$response = $client->lookup('0596157134'); 
var_dump($response); // Debugging
```

Is it possible with the API, or is there another way to get the product description and image?

Answer (score 5):

The item lookup call you are making only returns basic information about the product. You will need to use the ResponseGroup parameter to specify what information you want Amazon to return (see [Amazon's ItemLookup Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html) for more information). If you want to get the images and product description, you can request the "Medium" response group. Try the following call:

```
$response = $client->responseGroup('Medium')->lookup('0596157134');
```

Comment: Link is broken for their documentation, fyi.